# Is it obvious that if $T_1$ is both coarser and finer than $T_2$ on X, then the topologies are equal?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Based on the definition of finer and coarser topologies, please solve Ex 3.28, I am facing a hard time figuring out this. I thought of starting with $T_1$ and then taking a basis of that, do the same for $T_2$ and then show that the basis $B_1$ is a subset of $B_2$ which will mean that $T_1$ is a subset of $T_2$, but I got a problem in showing $T_1 \not= T_2$. So far, I have done a lot of problems where I proved or showed that $T_1 = T_2$ iff, both the bases are equal but now I have another condition $T_1 \not= T_2$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $T_1 \subset T_2$ and $T_2 \subset T_1$ $\implies$ $T_1 = T_2$.

Comment: I know that very well, but it tells me to use the fact that if $T_1$ is a subset of $T_2$, and $T_1 \not= T_2$. I don't think that's easy it is. lolz :P :D

Comment: The exercise uses the terms "coarser" and "finer" not "strictly coarser" and "strictly finer"...

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun the problem is only true if you interpret coarser and finer to allow equality. Otherwise you'd be trying to prove $T_1\neq T_2\Rightarrow T_1=T_2$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: The problem is still true for the strict versions, just vacuously so.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip well, it's certainly *true* that if $T_1$ is both strictly finer and strictly coarser than $T_2$ then this implies $T_1 = T_2$, but that's just because an impossibility implies anything.

Comment: oof, beaten to a vacuous truth joke by 2 seconds, that stings

Comment: I almost brought up the vacuous truth thing myself but I did not want to confuse the OP.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, yes.

Loosely, coarser means has fewer open sets.  Finer means has more open sets (depending on whether you're an analyst or an algebraist, it might be reversed).  But the outcome is unavoidable: the same open sets.

Comment: Ok, and how do I show that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are equal? I already know that $T_1$ is a subset of $T_2$, do I need to go in the other direction or just say that $T_2$ is a subset of $T_1$ ? Actually, my prof focuses on notations and expects us to give proper explanations, that's why I am concerned about this.

Comment: My understanding is that the terminology means that each topology is a subset of the other, which of course makes them equal.

Comment: But it doesn't say $T_2$ is a subset of $T_1$ anywhere, it says that $T_2 \not= T_1$, and it talks about finer and coarser topologies. That's where I am concerned the most.

Comment: Finer means a superset; coarser a subset.  With both we get equality.

Comment: You seem to be missing that finer and coarser are the opposite inclusions that you are looking for.

Comment: Oh k, finally found it. thanks a lot. I will be able to do it then.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathcal{T}_1$ is coarser and finer than $\mathcal{T}_2$ we have

$$\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}_2 \text{ from coarser} $$

$$\mathcal{T}_2 \subset \mathcal{T}_1 \text{ from finer} $$

And basic set theory tells us $\mathcal{T}_1 = \mathcal{T}_2$. That's all there is to it.

Notational point: I tend to use $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$ etc. to *explicitly* allow equality, but your text obviously already does allow it. To exclude equality it I'd use $\mathcal{T}_1 \subsetneq \mathcal{T}_2$ (for strictly coarser and strictly finer).

Bases are a read herring, don't mention them here.

Comment: Ok cool, but what’s the point of bringing coarser and finer topologies? What shud I say there? I don’t understand wat to write there.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun It's just convenient language for a situation that occurs quite often in practice. You can say that the order topology is the coarsest topology that makes all open segments/rays open. "smallest" would have done as well. It's coarser because if you have fewer open sets you cannot distinguish as many points topologically, sometimes. "weaker" and "stronger" are also used, in analysis e.g. I think it's a silly question, really.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun mathematicians like jargon I suppose.